# How to explain the difference between call and put price

Tags: stocks, options

[image: difference between call and put price at strike price 125]

How do I explain the difference between call and put price at strike price 125? I assume the call and put price will be very close, right? Thanks

Comment: There's no way to tell with just that information.  What's the price of the underlying and what's the expiration?

Comment: This is APPL stock and apple stock price right now is 109.30 USD. The expiration date is April 16th 2021

Comment: I feel I kind of understand now. But if someone can explain it, it will be better. Thanks

Comment: The stock price is now 109.30 USD, so the 125 USD put option has 15.70 USD (`125 - 109.30 = 15.70`) of intrinsic value, while the 125 USD call option has 0 USD of intrinsic value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you assume that the "call and put price will be very close?"  With the underlying stock being at $109.30, the $125 put is $15.70 in-the-money and should be 15 some odd dollars higher in price than the $125 call.

The midpoints of each option are pretty close to what they should be so these options are fairly valued.

Comment: Now I understand. This is my mistake. Thanks

Comment: I've edited under the assumption that $109 is the underlying.

Comment: Yep, that's descriptively clearer for those not following all of the comments.